# How to debug an Arduino program that won't compile?

Tags: c++, arduino

I wrote a program for Arduino for object avoiding using three ultrasonic sensors but it is giving error in compile. Why is the error coming and how I can resolve it?

```
int trigPin = 6;
int echoPin = 7;
int trigPin = 8;
int echoPin = 9;
int trigPin = 10;
int echoPin = 11;

int revleft4 = 2;
int fwdleft5 = 3;
int revright6 = 4;
int fwdright7 = 5;

long duration, distance, RightSensor,FrontSensor,LeftSensor;

void setup()
{
delay(random(500,2000));
Serial.begin (9600);
pinMode(revleft4, OUTPUT);
pinMode(fwdleft5, OUTPUT);
pinMode(revright6, OUTPUT);
pinMode(fwdright7, OUTPUT);

pinMode(trigPin1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(echoPin1, INPUT);
pinMode(trigPin2, OUTPUT);
pinMode(echoPin2, INPUT);
pinMode(trigPin3, OUTPUT);
pinMode(echoPin3, INPUT);
}

void loop() 

SonarSensor(trigPin1, echoPin1);
RightSensor = distance;
SonarSensor(trigPin2, echoPin2);
LeftSensor = distance;
SonarSensor(trigPin3, echoPin3);
FrontSensor = distance;


if(FrontSensor<=20 && LeftSensor<=20)
{
  Serial.println("Turn right");
  digitalWrite(fwdright7,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(revright6,LOW);
  digitalWrite(fwdleft5,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(revleft4,LOW);
}
else if(FrontSensor<=20 && RightSensor<=20)
{
  Serial.println("Turn left");

  digitalWrite(fwdright7,LOW);
  digitalWrite(revright6,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(fwdright5,LOW);
  digitalWrite(revright4,HIGH);
}
else
{
  Serial.println("Forward");

  digitalWrite(fwdright7,LOW);
  digitalWrite(revright6,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(fwdright5,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(revright4,LOW);
}
delay(5);
}


void SonarSensor(int trigPin,int echoPin)
{
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
delayMicroseconds(2);
digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
distance = duration/58.2; 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly when asking about build errors, always include the actual errors in the question body, copy-pasted as text in full and complete. Also add comments in the code to show where you get the errors.

Comment: A ***guess*** though: `void loop()` without an opening `{`. And that you call functions before they are declared.

Comment: Some programmer dude, The Arduino IDE makes it possible to call a function before it is declared. I don't think "normal" C++ compilers allow that.

Answer (score 1):

Arduinos error messages are very easy too understand. You basically just have to read them and fix what ever they complain about.

Compiling your code starts with:

```
FRF9LJ5IVO3SD4B:3:5: error: redefinition of 'int trigPin'

 int trigPin = 8;

     ^~~~~~~

..\FRF9LJ5IVO3SD4B\FRF9LJ5IVO3SD4B.ino:1:5: note: 'int trigPin' previously defined here

 int trigPin = 6;

     ^~~~~~~
```

So it is pretty obvious that you the variable trigPin multiple times.

A look at your code reveals:

```
int trigPin = 6;
int echoPin = 7;
int trigPin = 8;
int echoPin = 9;
int trigPin = 10;
int echoPin = 11;
```

that you actually defined trigPin and echoPin three times!

Later you use `trigPin1`, `trigPin2`, `trigPin3`, ...

After fixing this like

```
int trigPin1 = 6;
int echoPin1 = 7;
int trigPin2 = 8;
int echoPin2 = 9;
int trigPin3 = 10;
int echoPin3 = 11;
```

Compile again and we face

```
FRF9LJ5IVO3SD4B:34:1: error: expected initializer before 'SonarSensor'

 SonarSensor(trigPin1, echoPin1);

 ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

A quick look into your code

```
void loop() 

SonarSensor(trigPin1, echoPin1);
```

shows that you are missing `{` after `loop()` to open the block that defines `loop`

Add it, compile and we see

```
\FRF9LJ5IVO3SD4B\FRF9LJ5IVO3SD4B.ino: In function 'void loop()':

FRF9LJ5IVO3SD4B:56:16: error: 'fwdright5' was not declared in this scope

   digitalWrite(fwdright5,LOW);

                ^~~~~~~~~
```

So you're using `fwdright5` but you only declared `fwdright7` here

```
int revleft4 = 2;
int fwdleft5 = 3;
int revright6 = 4;
int fwdright7 = 5;
```

I don't know which one is the correct one you intended to use so I'll just delete any use of it to see which errors will pop up next.

Same with `revright4`. After fixing that your code compiles.

You need more focus and you have to actually read the error messages!